# How to count SharePoint list elements using CAML Query

Tags: javascript, caml-query, elements-xml

I have got CAML Query. How to count how many elements is in the list checked ?

Here is javascript code:

```
  var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Testowa Lista');
    //this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(j);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="Connect"/><Value Type="LookupMulti">site</Value></Contains></Where></Query><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>');
    this.listItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(listItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get total no.of items in a SharePoint List no need to insert query xml,

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Testowa Lista");

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
this.listItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(listItems);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));


function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) 
{
    var count = 0;
    count=this.listItems.get_count();
    alert("Total Count: "+count);

    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 
{
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

If you are trying to get no.of items based on a condition (example: `Title ='SampleTitle'`) then use CAML query,
Add query xml

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>SampleTitle</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
```

before this line,

```
this.listItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

Also refer this [Retrieve List Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185007(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: But i must selected - checed elements, so I must have ID of element.

Comment: And after this looped each of element.

Comment: Vishnu I need a selected items, not only count all items in a list, but selected.

Comment: @GrzegorzZ I have updated the answer, please check

Comment: Still Vishnu if I put the code to the button i can't fired the code. I click the button and nothing happening.

Comment: Splease look why it button not fired?

Comment: check if there is any error showing in the browser console.